# Privoxy blocking by host pattern doesn't work when HTTPS is used

Tags: privoxy

According to Privoxy documentation

> 4.15. How can Privoxy filter Secure (HTTPS) URLs?
>
> Since secure HTTP connections are encrypted SSL sessions between your browser and   the secure site, and are meant to be reliably secure, there is little that Privoxy can do but hand the raw gibberish data though from one end to the other unprocessed.
>
> **The only exception to this is blocking by host patterns**, as the client needs to tell Privoxy the name of the remote server, so that Privoxy can establish the connection. If that name matches a host-only pattern, the connection will be blocked.

blocking by host pattern should work independently of the protocol used (HTTP or HTTPS)

For instance:

`{ +block{Nasty ads.} }
.somesite.com/imp`

effectively blocks `http://test.somesite/imp` but not `https://test.somesite/imp`

The browsers I use are configured to use Privoxy proxy for both HTTP and HTTPS.

Is it a bug or an expected behavior, in spite of what the doc says? (I'm using v3.0.26)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a *path pattern*. It does not apply to CONNECT requests.

If, on the other hand, you have a [host pattern](https://www.privoxy.org/user-manual/actions-file.html#HOST-PATTERN), it will work no problem.

However, because the proxy cannot gracefully show the regular “blocked” page with HTTPS, it will just refuse the request. The browser will then display an error like “The proxy server is refusing connections”. This means you won’t be able to bypass the filter (if that option is even enabled).

Answer (score 2):

You will need to push your connection through a SSL supported proxy and have it forward the traffic back to the port you have privoxy running on.

Try using [Stunnel.org](https://www.stunnel.org). Be sure to edit the configuration to forward to port 8118 or whatever you have it listening on privoxy.

Comment: That's too much effort tbh, I'd recomment Fiddler which supports both HTTP and HTTPS and also supports Immersive Apps (Windows 8+ apps using AppContainer).